# Grep "out" matching and n subsequent lines

Tags: grep

Consider a log file which looks like this:

```
action A
detail 1
detail 2
detail 3
action X
detail 1
detail 2
action B
detail 1
action X
detail 1
detail 2
action C
```

Lines with "action [ABC]" may have various number of following "detail"-lines.

Lines with "action X" **always** have **2** following "detail"-lines.

I am not interested in event X so I would like to filter out all lines with "action X" and the following two lines.

I am aware of the `-v` flag, just not how to express the "and the following 2 lines" part.

Comment: Currently `grep` does not support context switches to be used with the `-v` switch, although there have been some suggestions to add it. I think `sed` would be the best alternative for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '/action X/{ N; N; d }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk alternative that does the same as *Nicole's* [`sed` answer](https://superuser.com/a/551946/133552):

```
awk '/action X/ { getline; getline; getline } 1'
```